# Applying values to a column based on value comparison in other columns across different rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have already searched the Internet for my problem but nothing quite the same. I am quite new in Pandas.

I have a huge dataframe, around 800K of rows. Out of 800K of rows, 200K of them are duplicates that indicate an owner who owns multiple cars under the same SSN (may have a different name due to spelling and such). For example, below is my dataframe.

SSN is the key in determining they are the same person albeit the name might be different (or slightly different) :

```
SSN_ID   Name              Registration_Number Brand       Car         Year    Eligible  Status   Channel 
00001    Baron Zemo        SKV2017             Toyota      86          2020    1         2        Call
00001    Baron Zimo        SKV1999             Subaru      BRZ         2012    1         0        Call
00002    Steve Rogers      SHD2012             Cadillac    deVille     1970    1         0        Call
00003    Bucky Barnes      MTL9841             Ford        Boss 429    1970    1         0        Call
00004    Tony Stark        IRN0007             Audi        R8          2013    1         1        Apps
00005    Wanda Maximoff    SCR1080             Hyundai     i-30N       2020    1         1        Apps 
00004    Tony Stank        ILY3000             Audi        e-Tron GT   2020    1         0        Call
00001    Beron Zemo        SKV0800             Audi        TT-RS       2018    1         1        Apps
```

The column 'Channel' is the channel where advertisement for insurance promotion will be done, and column 'Status' is the status of customer engagement.

```
'Status' = 0, No call attempted
'Status' = 1, Answered, rejected/accepted the offer
'Status' = 2, Unanswered, line busy/not pick-up
```

In before, the call and promotion is done based on each car, thus prompting the situation where an owner is called multiple times, once for each cars. For example above, Baron Zemo will be called 3 times at separate time/day, for each of his cars, since he owned 3 cars. But now, the management want to make sure each owner is called only once despite having multiple cars.

I want to update the column 'Channel' in the dataframe based on the 'Status' column value. The logic is supposed to be simply like this :

```
If 'Status' == 0 or 2, df[Channel] = 'Call'
If 'Status' == 1, df[Channel] = 'Apps'
```

But the thing is, owner with multiple cars, have multiple 'Status' across the rows. Take Zemo (SSN_ID : 00001) and Stark (SSN_ID : 00004) for example. They have multiple value for column 'Status' because they own multiple cars. Thus, I need to update the 'Channel' column based on 'Status' value on other rows as well.

Using `.loc`, I can split the dataframe into 2, 1 for owner with multiple car, and 1 with owner with 1 car.

```
df1= df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['SSN_ID'], keep=False)].sort_values(by='SSN_ID', ascending=True)

df2= df.loc[~(df.duplicated(subset=['SSN_ID'], keep=False))]
```

df1 is like below :

```
SSN_ID   Name              Registration_Number Brand       Car         Year    Eligible  Status   Channel 
00001    Baron Zemo        SKV2017             Toyota      86          2020    1         2        Call
00001    Baron Zimo        SKV1999             Subaru      BRZ         2012    1         0        Call
00001    Beron Zemo        SKV0800             Audi        TT-RS       2018    1         1        Apps
00004    Tony Stark        IRN0007             Audi        R8          2013    1         2        Apps
00004    Tony Stank        ILY3000             Audi        e-Tron GT   2020    1         0        Call
```

Eventho Zemo has 3 statuses (2,0,1), but since we have called Zemo on his Audi TT-RS ('Status'== 1) and he already rejected the offer, we should not bother to call him anymore (eventho he has 2 other cars), thus, column 'Channel' will be assigned to 'Apps'.

As for Stark, he has 2 statuses (2,0), since he didn not answer the call ('Status' == 2) , we would continue to try to call him until he answered and either reject or accept the offer, thus, column 'Channel' will be assigned to 'Call'.

However, I do not know how to apply those logic from above.

The final desired result for df1 is like below :

```
SSN_ID   Name              Registration_Number Brand       Car         Year    Eligible  Status   Channel 
00001    Baron Zemo        SKV2017             Toyota      86          2020    1         2        Apps
00001    Baron Zimo        SKV1999             Subaru      BRZ         2012    1         0        Apps
00001    Beron Zemo        SKV0800             Audi        TT-RS       2018    1         1        Apps
00004    Tony Stark        IRN0007             Audi        R8          2013    1         2        Call
00004    Tony Stank        ILY3000             Audi        e-Tron GT   2020    1         0        Call
```

Is there a way to do comparison across rows, and only update the value of the 'Channel' column correctly, without changing the dataframe shape (since it is still needed for something else) ?

Thank you so much.

Disclaimer : I know if the focus of the dataframe based on the SSN_ID instead of Car/Registration number, it will be easier, but this is for data manipulation practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this will help you get started. This should give you the `channel` column you are looking for.

```
d = {0:'Call',
1:'Apps'}

df['Channel'] = df['Status'].eq(1).groupby(df['SSN_ID']).transform('any').astype(int).map(d)
```

Comment: Brilliant! But can you break it down to me because I never knew or use `transform` and  `map`  before?

Comment: `transform` returns a series that is the same number of rows as the original df, and `map` can be used for value substitution. In this case it was pulling from the dictionary `d`.